# Cant find layout ID when going from Fragment to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a Bottom Navigation Application where we need to be able to go from one fragment to another (with a back button to return to the first fragment).
I can't figure out what to put for container view id to pass to the replace call. Everything I have tried shows unresolved reference.

```
class FoodLogFragment : Fragment() {
   private var _binding: FragmentFoodlogBinding? = null
   private lateinit var adapter: MealAdapter
   var startDate: Date = Date()

   // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
   // onDestroyView.
   private val binding get() = _binding!!

   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater,
       container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
       _binding = FragmentFoodlogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       val root: View = binding.root

       return root
   }

   fun handleAddButton(mealType: MealType) {
       val transaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        //problem is here
                        //there are no layout ids after R.id, or R.layout
       transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_foodcategory, FoodCategoryFragment())
       transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
       transaction.commit()
   }
```

Comment: You're using `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager`, so the ID needs to be the container in your activity's layout. Please include your activity's layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had gotten into my headers somehow

```
import android.R
```

Needs to be

```
import edu.trafficlightlog.R
```